# How can I simulate force drag?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use D3 Force Layout

I have button on web page. I want to have this animation http://take.ms/TYJsZ when I click the button.

So, I want to have small animation (similar to when it is initialized).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try,

`force.alpha(value)` the value is the cooling parameter. if the value is greater than one. then the force restarts. the lower value of cooling parameter determines the shake of your graph